# OnsenUI and Kendo pie chart issue

Tags: json, kendo-ui, onsen-ui, kendo-chart

I am using Kendo pie chart in onsenui framework and it works great if i use

```
function createChart() {
            $("#chart").kendoChart({
                title: {
                    position: "bottom",
                    text: "Share of Internet Population Growth, 2007 - 2012"
                },
                legend: {
                    visible: false
                },
                chartArea: {
                    background: ""
                },
                seriesDefaults: {
                    labels: {
                        visible: true,
                        background: "transparent",
                        template: "#= category #: \n #= value#%"
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    type: "pie",
                    startAngle: 150,
                    data: [{
                        category: "Asia",
                        value: 53.8,
                        color: "#9de219"
                    },{
                        category: "Europe",
                        value: 16.1,
                        color: "#90cc38"
                    },{
                        category: "Latin America",
                        value: 11.3,
                        color: "#068c35"
                    },{
                        category: "Africa",
                        value: 9.6,
                        color: "#006634"
                    },{
                        category: "Middle East",
                        value: 5.2,
                        color: "#004d38"
                    },{
                        category: "North America",
                        value: 3.6,
                        color: "#033939"
                    }]
                }],
                tooltip: {
                    visible: true,
                    format: "{0}%"
                }
            });
        }
```

I have my own JSON object which is $scope.localData
and when i replace the JSON `data` (which is inside `series`) with my localData, the chart doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you guys.

Here is my [codepen](http://codepen.io/ranjith_varadan/pen/raGLEo)

```
host : varanjith.com
username : demo
password : demo
```

Update #1

Brief Intro about the app, It gets the JSON object from web and store it in the local database, based on that data the pie chart is generated. Everything is working fine other than that chart. Please help

Update #2

I think i found out the problem, but still not sure, the kendo pie chart uses json as in the format

```
[{category:"Asia", value:87},{category:"Europe", value:97}]
```

but the $scope.localData has the value `[{"category":"Asia", "value":87},{"category":"Europe", "value":97}]`

I think that double quotation marks is the problem. Can anyone tell me how to remove it?

Comment: What are you trying to plot? `$scope.localData` contains some data but nothing that can be plotted as a pie chart.

Comment: I'm trying to plot the Country and Rating1 which is in $scope.localData but when i use the data from kendo pie chart official page, it works great.

Comment: Like this? http://codepen.io/argelius/pen/QwqKaZ

Doesn't look like data that can be shown in a pie chart.

Comment: Wow, You are a genius. What went wrong in my program? and yeah, i know, the data and the chart doesn't mean anything, it's just a demo content.

Comment: @AndreasArgelius post it as answer, so that i can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you're feeding to the Pie Chart looks malformed. I tried redefining the data with:

```
var data = $scope.localData.map(function(item) {
  return {
    category: item.Country,
    value: item.Rating1
  };
});
```

Also, I changed the template string back to `"#= category #: \n #= value#%"`. After doing that it worked fine.